# What size of meteoroid would be needed to wipe out humanity on Earth?

Tags: near-earth-asteroid

<sub>This might belong on physics.SE or astronomy.SE or not on SE at all as it's not falsifiable</sub>

I believe a meteoroid caused the dinosaurs to [go extinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triassic%E2%80%93Jurassic_extinction_event) by causing a global winter. However Earth has been impacted by various meteoroids even in [recent times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_event).

Assume a meteoroid of similar composition to Earth. How large does it have to be in order to cause a global winter for several years? Does the flight path affect that? For example I expect in prograde orbit almost anything will simply burn.

Comment: Depends on the kinetic energy. And on whether a global winter for several years would wipe out humanity; we've become pretty good at finding technological solution that would allow at least some people to survive.

Comment: "Asking for a friend."

Comment: Please read *all* the questions in https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=extinction

Comment: Is "wipe-out" "kill >50%" or "kill *every last person*"? The former requires destroying agriculture, while the latter may require a worse mass extinction than Earth has ever had, given holdouts on stored food.

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26457/could-planets-explode-in-space/26461#26461